# How to create people picker using jquery

Tags: 2013, jquery, people-picker, sandbox-solution

How to create people picker in sandbox solutions using jquery?

I need design part also.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom People picker.

Using 
jQuery,
[Select2](https://select2.github.io/),
[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download),
[SharePoint REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/libs/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Select2 CSS -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Scripts/libs/select2/select2.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Scripts/libs/select2/select2-bootstrap.css" />




function SetCustomPeoplePicker() {
  $("#peoplePickerDiv").select2({
     placeholder: "Search for a person",
     minimumInputLength: 3,
     ajax: {
         url: $.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"] + "/_api/web/siteusers",
         dataType: "json",
         data: function (term, page) {
         return {
             "$filter": "substringof('" + term + "', Title)"
         };
     },
     results: function (data, page) {
       return { results: data.d.results };
     },
     params: {
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: {
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
     }
   },
   id: function (person) { return { id: person.Id }; },
   formatResult: function (person) {
     return person.Title;
   },
   formatSelection: function (person) {
     return person.Title;
   },
   formatNoMatches: function () {
     return "No people found. (Case Sensitive)";
   },
   escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; },
   dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
   }).on('change', function (e) {
     // Access to full data
     console.log($(this).select2('data'));
   });
}
```

Comment: Please send me total design part also